# XML Schema maxOccurs and xs:all

Tags: xml, xsd

I got the following schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xs:element name="machine">
    <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="states" type="tokenList"/>
      <xs:element name="in_alphabet" type="tokenList"/>
      <xs:element name="blank" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="tape_alphabet" type="tokenList"/>
      <xs:element name="first_state" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="final_states" type="tokenList"/>

      <xs:element name="delta" type="delta_func" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

  <xs:simpleType name="tokenList">
    <xs:list itemType="xs:normalizedString"/>
  </xs:simpleType>

  <xs:complexType name="delta_func">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="state" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="read" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="target_states" type="tokenList"/>
      <xs:element name="write" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="move">
        <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
          <xs:pattern value="R|L|r|l"/>
        </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

Which works, but I would like to not restrict the order of the elements. I tried `xs:all` but it doesn't allow `maxOccurs=unbounded` for `delta`, which is a must. All other elements occur only once, so `xs:all` wouldn't be problem here. Is there a way to define random order on the element while allowing an unlimited numbers of `delta`s?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of  `<sequence>`, you could use `<choice maxOccurrs="unbounded">`, but it would imply that all elements can occur more than once.

Answer (score 4):

XSD 1.1 allows what you are looking for: xs:all with a maxOccurs on each element particle.