# XSD: unordered list of elements with different occurs possible?

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I have an element `A` with children `B` and `C`.
They can occur in **any order** but:

- `B` should unlimited or not at all
- `C` can occur only once or not at all

I tried to do it with `<xs:all>` but it doesn't accept `maxOccurs="unbounded"`.

Example Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="A">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:all>
                <xs:element name="B" minOccurs="0"
                            maxOccurs="unbounded" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="C" minOccurs="0" 
                            maxOccurs="1" type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:all>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Is here another way to accomplish this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2362365/xsd-doesnt-allow-me-to-have-unbounded-inside-all-indicator , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9097636/xml-schema-maxoccurs-and-xsall , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14622677/xml-schema-maxoccurs-unbounded-within-xsall

Comment: Already looked at this question/answers: `<xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">` does not fit my needs (as it would destroy the maxOccurs="1" of C)